# Chrome/chromium application automatic restart after update

Tags: chromium, google-chrome-app, auto-update, updating

I have been using autoupdate ( http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate ) with Chromium application and it seems to work great. However,I haven't been able to figure out how to automatically restart application after the update. The application is designed to run 24/7.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener(function () {
  chrome.runtime.reload();
});
```

Add that to your background page, [as described here](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onUpdateAvailable).